# Issues with sharing via LinkedIn API, response ok, but posts not showing

Tags: linkedin-api

We use LinkedIn API for past year to share on LinkedIn profiles and pages using API endpoints

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares
```

and

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{company-id}/shares
```

Response is always returned as:

```
{
  "updateKey": "UPDATE-xxxxx-xxxxxxx…",
  "updateUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/updates?discuss=…&scope=…"
}
```

But for past week when sharing some message with link included, posts/comments are not always showing, both on pages or on profiles, no matter response from API is OK with combination of updateKey and updateUrl.

Is this bug on LinkedIn API, or is there some restriction rule for API calls, where API accepts message with link included, and returns positive response with updateKey, but LinkedIn won't show up in feed?

Comment: I don't mind receiving negative points for this question, just need explanation why I received it.Still I think this is issue related with LinkedIn API, a possible bug. Only dev support seems to be through StackOverflow.

Comment: Niklaz we're observing similar behavior and believe it to be isolated to messages including specific links. Our current theory is that something on the pages being linked to is causing problems when LinkedIn tries to display a preview of them. Let us know if you figure anything else out and we'll do the same.

Comment: @matt.kauffman23, thanks for the reply, I will let you know what we discovered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar experience this week.  Our users were posting links through our app of links to youtube, and Linkedin would tell us everything is fine with a response like the one you posted.  We would mark it as successful in our system, but post would never show up.

Linkedin seemed to be scrubbing all of our links to videos (youtube, vimeo, etc).   Once we started adding a share image as well the links started showing up correctly.

Our solution was to always include an image when posting to Linkedin.

```
{ 'submitted-url' => <link user shared>, 'submitted-image-url' => <image of some kind> }
```

What we do is try to pull meta image from the link before publishing and use that.  If we can't find one we just pushed a 1px by 1px image.  Linkedin is now consistently sharing our posts.

If your issue is not with video urls I would look at if your links are maybe missing the correct meta tags for images.  As a fallback you could always try posting an invisible image like we did.

Comment: thanks for suggestions. This approach is working, and it worked before too. We use all relevant meta tags. The problem is when we send all content through 'comment' field. Until few days ago, it used to show a link preview card when some url was in comment field, if url had all necessary og:tags, however, now it doesn't even show the message :)

Comment: It looks like the posting url through comment, does not work any more in order to have a card preview. Thanks for suggestion